# Модуль importlib - как импортировать только функцию или константу, например <math.pi >, аналогично директиве < from math import pi >

Tags: python, импорт

Используя модуль < **importlib** > я могу импортировать модуль < **math** > так -

`globals()['math'] = importlib.import_module('math')`

, что аналогично директиве - `import math`

**???** Вопрос, а как мне импортировать только функцию или константу, например `math.pi`,

аналогично директиве `from math import pi`, также используя строковое название функции.

Comment: Сперва импортируйте модуль, а потом из модуля вытащите нужный вам объект

Answer (score 1):

Проверено, так работает корректно:

```
globals()['pi'] = importlib.import_module('math').__dict__['pi']
```

Comment: Сработает некорректно при попытке получить `zoneinfo.TZPATH` например

Comment: Для неустановленного пакета это вроде как естественно. Попробовал поставить его через pip, не вышло, покопался, и если я правильно понял этот пакет появляется только начиная с версии 3.9   У меня 3.8  проверить не могу. Поясните новичку суть вашего сообщения.